# JavaScript file can't work while the code work with node in Terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js

I start a java client listening on localhost:8887
And I try this

```
var net = require('net')
var coon = net.connect(8887,'127.0.0.1')
coon.write('hi')
coon.destroy()
```

in Terminal with node. The client get the message.
Then I write it into a file test.js and use 'node test.js' in the Terminal, but the client can't get the message. How can I solve this problem.
I add
    console.log(coon.remoteAddress+':'+coon.remotePort)
in the code. When I run 'node test.js', it shows that 'undefined:undefined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are you type into the terminal slow enough for the connection to be made. When you run the whole script, you're attempting to `write` before there is a connection.

Use the 3rd *connectionListener* argument

```
const coon = net.connect(8887, 'localhost', () => {
    coon.write('hi');
    coon.destroy();
});
```

See https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_connect_port_host_connectlistener